# JIRA order issues by id giving unexpected results

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jql

I am trying to sort my jira issues across all projects by id. The results I am getting however seem to be sorting on some other condition (maybe key?).

For example, hitting this endpoint: /rest/api/latest/search?jql=ORDER+BY+id+desc

Gives me the following output [image: jira output]

Notice that the issues are clearly not sorted by ID, but appear to be sorted correctly within each project. I, however, need to be able to sort by ID across all projects.

Answer (score 0):

Odd. With 8.13.13 Data Center and
/rest/api/latest/search?jql=ORDER+BY+id+desc&fields=id
the order looks as expected to me